# Alinco DR-635 programming software

Tags: yaesu, alinco, chirp

I see that RT-Systems sells programming software and a cable so you can program the Alinco DR-635's internal memory via your laptop instead of through the Alinco's cryptic and hostile user interface. Has anybody tried this product? Is its user interface any better than that of the Alinco itself? I'd hate to pay $50 for this and find it just as buggy and poorly-documented as the Alinco.

If I decide to give up on the Alinco and switch to a Yaesu 2-meter rig, which Yaesu's are CHIRP-programmable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to how it compares to the Alinco software, but I've used the RT software for a few different radios and it's straightforward, if pricey.

But $50 for the RT solution is probably cheaper than a new mobile/base rig, and if I were in your shoes it's the route I'd take.

As for CHIRP compatibility for Yaesu radios, [check out the project's compatibility page](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Supported_Radios).

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thank you for your advice!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have a different model Alinco radio.  I presume that the "cryptic and hostile user interface" you speak of is not the front panel of the radio, but rather part of Alinco's programming software.

I didn't want to pay for RT-Systems' expensive software and cable, so I persevered and figured out Alinco's software.  What helped a lot was programming a memory through the front panel of the radio, and then seeing how the software saw that memory slot.

The list of radio models supported by CHIRP is right on their [home page](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home).

Comment: yes indeed, my problem is with the programming instructions in the user manual, which clank bigly. Also, I am not a programmer myself and have none of the skills needed to do what you did!

Comment: I can relate!  Sounds like RT-Systems is your best bet then.  I'm really happy with my Alinco now that I can program it.